# NSSortDescriptor For Double Value Behaving Strangely

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nssortdescriptor

I have an NSSet which contains the following values:

> {0.5, 0.01, 0.05, 5, 1, 0.25, 25, 10, 100}

I want to sort the contents of this set into an array of numbers from low to high using NSSortDescriptor. Of course, so as not to render the following...:

> {0.01, 0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 10, 100, 25, 5}

...I must use the @selector(localizedStandardCompare:) attribute of an NSSortDescriptor instance.

The following is my code:

```
    NSMutableArray *valuesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[valuesSet allObjects]];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortedOrderSpecifier = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];

    [valuesArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortedOrderSpecifier]];

    return valuesArray;
```

But - the output here is wrong too, but just barely! Its weird:

> {0.01, **0.5**, 0.05, 0.25, 1, 5, 10, 25, 100}

As I have bolded above, you can see that 0.5 is not correctly positioned, but everything else is fine.  So what makes this value so special, and why is it breaking localizedStandardCompare?

Thanks!

Comment: The use of `localizedStandardCompare:` implies that your values are strings, not numbers. Why aren't you using numbers?

Comment: Hmm...so since if I make these of String type, it will sort correctly then.  Okay; that shouldn't be difficult since I do very little math and a lot of assignment to UI elements.  Was just hoping I wouldn't have to bother.  I am still curious as to why I must do this as according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898480/nssortdescriptor-not-sorting-integers-correctly it should work properly, and by all accounts save the '0.5' it does.  I'm wondering what could explain the output in this instance.

Comment: It appears to be a bug in `localizedStandardCompare:`. I just repeated the same problem. Since they are numbers, you should use numbers. When you want to shown them to the user, convert them to strings using `NSNumberFormatter`. This way the numbers appear properly to the user based on their locale. Example: `0.5` should appear as `0,5` to users in many countries.

Comment: That is a good point.  Thank you rmaddy!